# DataTables Firefox empty <th>&nbsp</th> css border bug

Tags: css, html, datatables

There seems to be a bug in firefox with DataTables where the left border is missing and the bottom border has double width for the last `<th>&nbsp;</th>` column in the table. see attached pic.

[image]

Comment: Can you please share the live website link?

Comment: It requires a login for the page to be viewed. fyi it works perfectly in safari and chrome

Comment: @user3213561 Can you copy the relevant HTML & CSS and make a snippet or [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had column width set on the other columns except this one. Once I set a column width the borders displayed correctly.